# What are fonts that starts with "@"?

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I'm listening the fonts installed on the computer thought a script but I found those fonts whose name starts with a @, such as `@Yu Gothic UI`. What's the different from such font from one without the "@" at start of the name, say, such as `Yu Gothic UI`? I've tried to use them at work, to me, they look like exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fonts which begin with an @-sign are vertically-oriented fonts. They are used in languages like Chinese, Japanese, and (less often) Korean. The idea is that if you want to generate vertical text, you start with the horizontal version of the font and compose your document, then switch to the vertical version for printing.

For more details, please refer to the following article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Horizontal_and_vertical_writing_in_East_Asian_scripts&oldid=460123882#Vertical_writing_and_computers